# Prove the equality: $H_{\tau_1, \tau_2} + \mathcal{H}(p(Q|\tau_1, \tau_2)) = \mathcal{H}(p(Q))$

Tags: probability, information-theory

Let $Q$ be a random variable and $\tau$ be some parameters. Let us define a summation of KL divergences 
$$H_{\tau_1, \tau_2} = D_{KL}(p(Q|\tau_1, \tau_2)\Vert p(Q|\tau_1)) + D_{KL}(p(Q|\tau_1)\Vert p(Q)) $$

It is said that the following equality holds 
$$H_{\tau_1, \tau_2} + \mathcal{H}(p(Q|\tau_1, \tau_2)) = \mathcal{H}(p(Q))$$ where $\mathcal{H}(\cdot)$ is the entropy.

I am quite confused about how to prove the validity of the equality above.

Comment: Are $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ constants or random variables? I doubt that this is true if they are not random.

Comment: @Arash  They are not random variables. But I don't know how to prove rigorously the equality holds.

Comment: If they are not random variables, then what is the meaning of $p(Q|\tau_1)$? Let me be more clear about previous comment. I meant that if they are not random variable then I do not how to interpret $p(Q)$ and $p(Q|\tau_1)$? are they NOT dependent on $\tau_2$? how is their dependence on $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$? Indeed if they are random variable then it is straightforward to show this using only linearity of expectation.